# how to generate hash of flowfile attribute (some of them)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a `flowfile` with 3 attributes a, b, c. I want to create 2 new attributes `a_b_hash`, `c_hash`.

```
a_b_hash = hash of (value of a + '_' + value of b)
c_hash = hash of c
```

So at the end I want 5 attributes `a`, `b`, `c`, `a_b_hash`, `c_hash`. with a, b, c unchanged.

I tried different combinations, but not able to generate hash. Some permutations work, but then I don't know if it is generating correct has.

---

Update

I created following template and ran it. I was expecting `a_hash` and `c_hash` to have same value, `a` and `c` have same value.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><template encoding-version="1.2"><description></description><groupId>ae48862f-0165-1000-cc45-c1efcbb7ff08</groupId><name>dnu-hash-attribute</name><snippet><connections><id>91ef00b9-6cd0-3fed-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>5cf06895-44e9-3f64-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>9b4dd5b8-8718-3f54-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>2fbfd09e-72e8-3c46-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>ab89e6d1-f08e-32be-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>5cf06895-44e9-3f64-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>4e1f1096-d302-35f8-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>9b4dd5b8-8718-3f54-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>509810d8-4798-30e5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><processors><id>9b4dd5b8-8718-3f54-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>89.14968895009349</x><y>271.1685572155761</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Hash Value Attribute Key</key><value><name>Hash Value Attribute Key</name></value></entry><entry><key>a</key><value><name>a</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Hash Value Attribute Key</key><value>a_hash</value></entry><entry><key>a</key><value>(?s)(^.*$)</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>HashAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>true</autoTerminate><name>failure</name></relationships><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>ab89e6d1-f08e-32be-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>634.6037608433834</x><y>574.9859619140625</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Log Level</key><value><name>Log Level</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value><name>Log Payload</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key><value><name>Attributes to Log</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-log-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key><value><name>Attributes to Ignore</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-ignore-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key><value><name>Log prefix</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Log Level</key><value>info</value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value>.*</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>LogAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>true</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>DISABLED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>509810d8-4798-30e5-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>492.20976365100057</x><y>0.0</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>File Size</key><value><name>File Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value><name>Batch Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value><name>Data Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value><name>Unique FlowFiles</name></value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key><value><name>generate-ff-custom-text</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry><entry><key>a</key><value><name>a</name></value></entry><entry><key>b</key><value><name>b</name></value></entry><entry><key>c</key><value><name>c</name></value></entry><entry><key>d</key><value><name>d</name></value></entry><entry><key>e</key><value><name>e</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>File Size</key><value>20000B</value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value>1</value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value>Text</value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry><entry><key>a</key><value>aaa</value></entry><entry><key>b</key><value>t</value></entry><entry><key>c</key><value>aaa</value></entry><entry><key>d</key><value>ow</value></entry><entry><key>e</key><value>two</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>1 day</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>GenerateFlowFile</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile</type></processors><processors><id>5cf06895-44e9-3f64-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>0.0</x><y>525.5136022177769</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Hash Value Attribute Key</key><value><name>Hash Value Attribute Key</name></value></entry><entry><key>c</key><value><name>c</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Hash Value Attribute Key</key><value>c_hash</value></entry><entry><key>c</key><value>(?s)(^.*$)</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>HashAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>true</autoTerminate><name>failure</name></relationships><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashAttribute</type></processors></snippet><timestamp>09/27/2018 12:16:54 EDT</timestamp></template>`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NiFi comes with a processor called `HashAttribute`. The usage of which is like, you can add dynamic properties where the name of the new property would be the name of the FlowFile and the value is a regex, you can provide `(?s)(^.*$)` to capture the FlowFile attribute value in its entirety.

**Flow**

[image]

**HashAttribute - a and b**

[image]

*HashAttribute - c*

[image]

**Resultant FlowFile Attributes**

[image]

Comment: Please look at my update. either I am doing something wrong or I cant explain why same string value is generating 2 different hash.

Comment: That is because it hashes the key and value together. So, even when you have same values, the keys i.e. FlowFile attribute names are different and that is why you're getting different values. Take a look at this block: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/HashAttribute.java#L214-L221

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `CryptographicHashAttribute` which is now available in Apache NiFi 1.8.0-SNAPSHOT (1.8.0 is not yet released). I hope to deprecate `HashAttribute` and provide the new functionality described in [NIFI-5582](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5582) in 1.8.0 when it is released as well (I have a branch almost done but have been working on some other priorities lately).

Right now, the behavior doesn't allow for arbitrary string concatenation, so you would have to use an `UpdateAttribute` processor to populate an attribute *a_b* with the Expression Language expression `${a}_${b}` to perform the concatenation, and then `HashAttribute` *a_b_hash* -> `a_b` with the **Attribute Matching Strategy** set to `Individual`. The *c_hash* -> `c` could be done without any additional processors.